# why does `mfp start` exit with code 1 when the server was started successfully?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm finding that when `mfp start` is run that it returns `1` when it starts the server and `0` when the server was already running.

This breaks the exit status convention of a successful command completing with a code of `0` (and some tooling at assumes that meaning).

To me, whether or not the server was already started, the command completes with the desired result (the server running), so they should both return `0`.

Or is there some other meaning/purpose to be derived from the different exit codes?

Comment: Thanks for the question. This is being investigated by the development team.

Answer (score 1):

@N2O Thank you for reporting this. This definitely seems like a defect and APAR ticket PI43410 has been opened to track this issue. To receive the iFix when ready, you can open a PMR (support ticket), mentioning this question/APAR number